# Get complete filepath for cached images

Tags: javascript, image, caching

I have figured out how to preload images. What I am trying to find out now is whether there is any way, using Javascript, to get the local filepath where an image has been cached.

Comment: No, this isn't possible. Out of curiosity, why would you want to do it?

Comment: uploading image files using inputs, later  inputs values repopulated with uploaded filenames (filepath of files on server) and thumb of image displayed in div. After updates are made to input values I need inputs not changed (still containing filepath on server) to be filled with a cached image (need full filepath). Since I need local filename for upload to work.  I want to use a cached image as a place holder to maintain size of an initial image array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of FileReader and sessionStorage.
Something like:

```
var input = document.querySelector("#imageInput");
input.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt){
        var newImage = document.createElement("img");
        newImage.src = evt.target.result;
        document.querySelector("body").appendChild(newImage);
        sessionStorage.setItem("image", evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}, false);

window.addEventListener("load", function(e){
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("image")){
        var newImage = document.createElement("img");
        newImage.src = sessionStorage.getItem("image");
        document.querySelector("body").appendChild(newImage);
    }
}, false);
```

That would store all of your images on the browser and have them persist through posts and reloads. Then you can add any logic to edit them as you need.

Unfortunately, you can't set inputs of type "file" so you'll need to do some UI magic.

Comment: O.K.  I have been using filereader to show an image of files to be updated.  First I have heard about session storage.  This is what I am looking for.  Thanks much